# PHP syntax for arrays: different behaviour between PHP versions

Tags: php, linux, windows

I made a PHP page with an array using the following syntax:

```
$Legenda = [
    "Cores"      => ["#FF0000", "#FFA500", "#FFFF00", "#64FF00", "#00AA00", "#005500", "#0000FF"],
    "ValMinimos" => [50,         62.85714,  75.71429,  88.57143, 101.42857, 114.28571, 127.12286],
    "ValMaximos" => [62.85714,   75.71429,  88.57143, 101.42857, 114.28571, 127.12286, 140]
];
```

which works fine on windows (PHP 5.4.6, installed using EasyPHP), but when I uploaded the same page to a Ubuntu Server (PHP 5.3.10, installed using apt-get from repositories), I get an error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /var/www/ShapeTest_server_get_dados.php on line 13". Line 13 is the $Legenda array definition.

It's been a while since I programmed with PHP, but as I remember that syntax was valid. Is this an option turned off by default on linux, or why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [shortened array](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/shortsyntaxforarrays) [syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) was only added in PHP 5.4: [**Arrays**](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces `array()` with `[]`.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

[**Live result**](http://3v4l.org/C3b6T)