# Fetching Data from Mysql and filling Inputs

Tags: php, ajax

I've got the following mysql table (expensemonthly):

[image]

I'm trying to fill inputs text in a form with the account_id (and account name fetch from another mysql table called "accounts"), for doing that from ajax code below I call a php file (CountFetchExpensesArrayDos.php) for creating a two dimention array:

```
//Count Registers and Fill Inputs
    $('#count').click(function(){ 
     
           $.ajax({  
                url:"CountFetchExpensesArrayDos.php", 
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',               
                data:{monthyear:"112021"},  
                success:function(data){
                    // array Receive
                        alert(data);
                        AddInputs(data.count);
                        alert("Se detectaron: "+data+" registros");
                        FillExpensesInputs(data.count,data.account_id,data.name);                                           
                    
              }  
           });  
        });
```

Below the CountFetchExpensesArrayDos.php file for getting data from the month (112021):

```
$Month = $connect->real_escape_string($_POST['monthyear']);
//Count number of month registers
$sqlc = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM expensemonthly WHERE yearmonth = '$Month'");
$count=$sqlc->num_rows;
    
if(! $connect ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
         
//Get account_id and name for the month registers
$sql = "SELECT * FROM expensemonthly,accounts WHERE yearmonth = '$Month' AND accounts.account_id=expensemonthly.account_id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$final_array = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $final_array[] = $row['account_id'];           
        $final_array[] = $row['name'];      
    }
    $CountArray[] = $count;
    //Merge Array with number of register for the month, account_id,name
    $Totalarray = array_merge($CountArray,$final_array);
    //Send array to ajax
    exit(json_encode($Totalarray));
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

My problem is that when data is arriving to ajax in an unknown format, If show data "`alert(data)`;" I see it comma separated, but I cannot splitted using javascript "split() Method", I need to split data receive for filling Inputs in the form, this the data as received in ajax:

[image]

Please any Ideas? If there another method to get data from month using php and pass it to Ajax?

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your AJAX code is expecting an associative array with 3 keys: `count`, `account_id`, and `name`. You're not creating an associative array in the PHP code. You're just appending each account ID and name as separate array elements.

You can create and push onto separate arrays for the account IDs and names. Then put them in the associative array when creating the JSON at the end.

```
//Get account_id and name for the month registers
$sql = "SELECT * FROM expensemonthly,accounts WHERE yearmonth = '$Month' AND accounts.account_id=expensemonthly.account_id";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
$account_ids = array();
$names = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        $account_ids[] = $row['account_id'];           
        $names[] = $row['name'];    
    }
    //Merge Array with number of register for the month, account_id,name
    $Totalarray = array('count' => $count, 'account_id' => $account_ids, 'name' => $names);
    //Send array to ajax
    exit(json_encode($Totalarray));
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
mysqli_close($connect);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed ,my code as you suggest, but I receive the following erro on lines: $account_ids = [];
$names = [];                                                                                                      $Totalarray = ['count' => $count, 'account_id' => $account_ids, 'name' => $names];

Comment: What error did you receive?

Comment: Barmar Thanks for your answer, I changed ,my code as you suggest, but I receive the following error on 3 lines The same for the 3 lines):                                                                                                                        Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' on line 19                                                              $account_ids = [];
$names = [];                                                                                                      $Totalarray = ['count' => $count, 'account_id' => $account_ids, 'name' => $names];

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? It sounds like you're using an old version that doesn't support array literals, so you have to use `array(...)` instead of `[...]`.

Comment: This syntax has been supported since PHP 5.4. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439622/php-syntax-for-arrays-different-behaviour-between-php-versions

Comment: I've got PHP 5.2.5, Please Do you know the sintax for that PHP version?

Comment: You really should upgrade. But I already edited the question to show the older syntax.

Comment: I also described it in the comment: `[...]` becomes `array(...)`. This should be basic syntax that you already know.